# I added "notify-send hi user" to startup command but it is not working. How can i make it work?

Tags: startup, notify-send

If I put "notify-send hi user" in terminal it shows notification. But when the same command is put into startup applications it does not work. I want to use this in my qt application

Answer (score -1):

Try this

In terminal,

```
$sudo vim /home/user/hi.sh   

#!/bin/sh
sleep 3
echo "Hi User!" | xargs -0 notify-send
```

save it.

In terminal

```
$gnome-session-properties
```

add
sh /home/user/hi.sh

Reboot and see if you can see Hi User!